# Flash Testing for Android Phones

Tags: android, flash, adobe, cs4

Okay,

I'm and unemployed student and i want to make a game for one of adobe's mobile game contest for android phones and flash 10.1

Well, although i have cs4, i dont have cs5, and dont have the money to upgrade or buy a test phone.

So i was wondering is there still anyway to emulate testing on the android platform with flash 10.1 games, or am i out of luck.

I have the android sdk and eclipse plugin, is their by chance a way i can test the swf's from there.

**Edit: I might have a possible solution. I have recently learned that the Device Central in the cs5 might not expire after 30days, which would be really helpful if i can at least still test out the swf's, but just not use flash cs5. Of course i wont know for sure until a month for now ( just installed cs5 ), but im gonna ask on the adobe forums to see if i can get a faster response, and thought there might be some people who might want to know about a answer.**

Comment: I don't think the emulator can run flash

Comment: You should probably take a second look at the tools. If you use Flash Builder (i.e. what used to be Flex Builder), that's currently free for anyone who is a student or unemployed. (I think for noncommercial use.) See: https://freeriatools.adobe.com/ Also, the student-only pricing for Flash authoring is pretty cheap.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that I could recommend:

1. Read this post which runs through testing a SWF with the tools you already have. Not only that but it looks like the SWF can be compiled with CS4.
    
    http://www.flashmobileblog.com/2009/08/12/flash-development-with-android-sdk-1-5/
2. If you feel like you must have CS5, check the rules and regulations for the contest you might be able to download the trial version of CS5 which usually is good for 30 days.

Comment: I was thinking of getting the cs5 trial, but i dont want to to download and install it just for this one time, although i may make an exception.

I think that link is for flash lite, where as the dev contests are i think targeting android 2.2 and its support of 10.1

Thanks Anyways ( Also, you said "1" twice :) )